# SQL Connections not working on windows 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, windows

I am learning vb and connecting my program to MS SQL server 2014, which is run on a separate server, its been working fine developing on windows 8.1.

I recently updated to windows 10 and .net framework 4.6. after which time my automatic detection of all sql instance on the network stopped working - I could still enter a path directly to connect just not list all network sql instances.

Other machines running the program on the network are all fine (windows 8.1)

I downgraded the .net frame work to 4.5 and then 4 but didn't make any difference

Not a problem really as could connect via direct server/instance string

Windows 10 update this week, and now the windows 10 machine cant see the sql instance at all, even putting the direct server/instance details into the program it wont find anything or connect to anything. cant postimages at the moment as rep less then 10 :/

any help would be most appreciated as this has brought me to a bit of a halt and I cant find a similar error on the web

Comment: Defaul intalation of ms sql many years has disabled TCP/IP protocol

Comment: I believe that this question should be moved to http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 machine in the domain as the server? Can you ping the server from the W10 machine?

Comment: HI Guys thanks so much for your replies, yes I had tcpip protocol on and the machine was in the same domain as the sqql server and could ping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the help here guys this is what I found to be wrong (bit out of the box)

the machine was previously used by my boss as a test machine for hyper v, so the network card was virtualised and the computer connecting to the network through a virtual switch..

after trying every thing else :) I finally noticed this and removed the hyper v settings and reenabled ipv6 (as it wouldn't ping the sql server and other machines on my network that could connect to sql seemed to be able to, but got an ipv6 response not ipv4) which was disabled on the card and it all leapt into life.

easy when you know where to look.

thanks again for the replies , much appreciated